# can we preview blogs in SharePoint online site before click on publish button

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, publishing-site, blog

We need to add blogs to the sharepoint online site , to achieve this we have created a blog site(sub-site under main site). In this blog site we will add data in **Posts** list and click on **publish** button. After publishing list item we are getting data from that list and displaying in main site as a page. It is working fine.

But now we got a requirement that customer need to preview blog before clicking on Publish button.

Is there any way to achieve this ? Please help

Thanks in Advance.